# question about candle type tradingview alertcondition and plotshape

Tags: pine-script, trading, tradingview-api

i've been looking around to find my answers for a few hours now.. i cant find anything

when i change candle type on tradingview for (Heikin ashi) my plotshape trigger at different interval, but i'm now wondering if its also affecting my alertcondition() using the same variable as my plotshape ?

my setting in chart setting symbol are also set to : real prices on price scale (instead of heikin ashi prices) not sure if that affect my script either.

I saved my new alarm but usually when i make a change to the script itself i get a new option in the create alert : condition menu with the new version.. but now i dont get any other options.

does the UI in chart affect the pine script or not. my script does not make any modifiction to the candles itself. i just change the candles type in the menu

thanks

Answer (score 1):

HA close is based on averaging which is the nature of the bar type. Indicators and other conditions are based on the close price which does not reflect real close, hence the differentiation in behaviour. This is expected.

Cheers and all the best

Comment: thanks for the answer ! im still not sure i understand why plotshape is painted at different times than my alertcondition() with the same condition. "variable" pinescript is very confusing compared to other language to me